# opening Sublime Text (or other text editor) from command line as root on Mac OS

Tags: macos, text-editors, root, sublime-text-3, .profile

I've modified my `/var/root/.profile` using nano (this is the only editor which works with root for some reason(. Ridiculous, I know))):

```
export EDITOR="subl -w"
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

but when I try to open any text file using `subl filename` it's trying for a few seconds and then says:

```
Unable to connect to Sublime Text
```

If I do the same as regular user it works great!
(Modified the `~/.profile` instead of `/var/root/.profile`)

BTW, if I do this as root:

```
open -e filename
```

it says:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/TextEdit.app with error -10810 for the file /private/var/root/.profile.
```

What's wrong with my root user? Why I can use only nano editor as root? It drives me crazy!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Sublime Text 2, unless you manually changed the name of the `.app` file, the command should be:

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

Note the filename is `Sublime Text 2.app`, and also note that only double quotes are needed, not double surrounding single.

Comment: Forgot to clarify, I'm using Sublime Text 3 and it's filename is Sublime Text.app. Besides as I said before - If I do the same as regular user it works great!

Comment: @Andrew you had tagged your question as ST2, which is why I gave that answer.